# Bash: how to trap set -e, but not exit

Tags: bash, exit-code

My scripts have as first instruction:

```
set -e
```

So that whenever an error occurs, the script aborts. I would like to trap this situation to show an information message, but I do not want to show that message whenever the script exits; ONLY when set -e triggers the abortion. Is it possible to trap this situation?

This:

```
set -e

function mytrap {
    echo "Abnormal termination!"
}

trap mytrap EXIT

error

echo "Normal termination"
```

Is called in any exit (whether an error happens or not), which is not what I want.

Comment: Call a function at normal exit points such that it sets a flag to indicate normal termination.  This value can be checked by your trap function to distinguish between normal and abnormal termination.

Comment: @codeforester Yepp, I was thinking now on those terms. A bit cumbersome though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `trap` on `EXIT`, use it on `ERR` event:

```
trap mytrap ERR
```

**Full Code:**

```
set -e

function mytrap {
   echo "Abnormal termination!"
}

trap mytrap ERR

(($#)) && error

echo "Normal termination"
```

Now run it for error generation:

```
bash sete.sh 123
sete.sh: line 9: error: command not found
Abnormal termination!
```

And here is normal exit:

```
bash sete.sh
Normal termination
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the "ERR" trap.  Nicely explained, @anubhava!

Comment: Thanks anubhava. Not the first time I see how profficient you are in bash. Do you have any tips on advanced bash programming? Links or books are welcome!

Comment: `(($#))` means `$# > 0` which means if an argument is passed to script. `(($#)) && error` means execute `error` if argument is passed to script. About your earlier comments: Thanks for the encouraging words. I have learnt most of it while working and more importantly while reading answers from bash experts here on Stackoverflow